# Yii clientScript Render Throws Error

Tags: php, yii

I have the following in a partial view:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('nivo-slider');
Yii::app()->clientScript->render();
```

However, I receive an error stating `Missing argument 1 for CClientScript::render(),`

What arguments does the render method require?  I checked the docs but couldn't find anything definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They seem pretty clear to me](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#render-detail). You need to pass it a reference variable which will hold the value of the rendered string.

```
// as an example:
$output = NULL;
Yii::app()->clientScript->render($output);
// you can now do something with output!
```

Comment: So, $output is a required variable?  Since I've already registered the Package in the line above, what value does the $output variable need?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I used NULL above.